# Printing specific rows and specific columns from a data frame Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset with 1000 rows and 26 columns named as, say, 'A',...,'Z'. I want to print from say, rows 25 to 40 for specific columns, say, G, P, and Z. How do I do that?  I tried with loc[] and iloc[] ways. All of these work when specific rows and cols are mentioned explicitly. If the dataset is large and I want to print a set of rows as mentioned above. I could not find a way. Any working solution is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `.loc` for what you want (documentation is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)).

You can use slicing to achieve the desired behaviour, e.g.:

```
print(df.loc[25:40, ['G', 'P', 'Z']].to_string())
```

As the first elements (`25:40`) use the index of your DataFrame, these might not be sorted integers, so you could do the following to get the desired behaviour:

```
print(df.reset_index().loc[25:40, ['G', 'P', 'Z']].to_string())
```